# Match array of ids from pivot table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Scenario

I have 3 main tables  `Employees`,`Jobs`,`Skills`. `Employees` and `Jobs` has `many-to-many` relationship with `Skills` table.

So, an employee can have skills `1,2,3,5`. A `job` may requires `skills` `1,3,5`.

Now my question is how can I match the id's in an eloquent query. Like, if I want to search all the `employees` for a `job` requiring `skills 1,3,5`, it should search all the `employees` having all those `skills(1,3,5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you have an array of IDs, so use multiple `whereHas()`:

```
$employees = Employee::JobLocations($jobZipId);

foreach ($skillIds as $id) {
    $skilledEmployees = $emloyees->whereHas('skills', function ($q) use ($id) {     
        $q->where('id', $id);
    });
}

$skilledEmployees = $skilledEmployees->get();
```

Comment: now it's not returning any records. I find another way to match the ids. After pulling the records, I can match with `count(array_intersect(array_unique($employeeSkillIds), $jobSkillIds)) == count($jobSkillIds);` but this doesn't look good and it would be great if I can perform the same task within eloquent.

Comment: I needed to modify the code a bit http://pastie.org/10956748 . Can you please update your answer and I'll accept it. Thanks a ton!

Comment: @shoieb0101, in your code you have 3 variables ($employees , $allEmployees, $testEmployees). Are you sure in those? Could you check this please.

Comment: I've update pastie. please check now. I used different variable names just to test. Your one is working just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like, I am taking `$job` as already a defined object.

```
Employee::whereHas('skills', function($q) use($job) {
     $q->whereIn('id', $job->skills->lists('id')->toArray());
})->get();
```

**Update**

In case of Laravel 5.3 and up, the method `lists` won't work (as its is removed) so you can also use `pluck` method instead of `lists`.

Hope this helps you to solve your problem.

Comment: I tried like that before but it does not match array of ids, it just matches a single item from employee_skills with job_skill ids and returns true. I need to return true only if all the ids in `$job->skills->lists('id')->toArray()` are present in `$employee->skills->lists('id')->toArray()`.

Comment: I'm using 5.2 and getting the `ids` in an array is not issue.

Comment: I think whereIn will compare all of them using 'and' operator comparison as for reference see this - https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereIn

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi, `whereIn()` is looking for `any` and not `all` entries.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin, `whereIn()` uses 'and' whereas `orWhereIn()` uses or if you see the docs - https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_orWhereIn

Comment: @SaumyaRastogi, from docs: The whereIn method verifies that a given column's value is contained within the given array. So it will find all employees who has one of the skills, but not employees who have all skills.